# Weather API, How this(see screenshot attached) bar works? Why the bar slides left or right and why bar width increases or decreases?

Tags: javascript, weather

The screenshot was taken from https://darksky.net/forecast/37.1889,-112.9986/us12/en

[image: attached image]

Comment: The bar has a min and max range. It doesn't start at min and max, it starts at the low of the day and end at the high of the day.

Comment: It makes sense. I'll let you know if I face a problem while working. Thanks

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense It's not helpful. This method becomes problematic when the temperature becomes extremely hot or cold. Looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you want then you should change the styles yourself. This is the rendered html on the page for the bars.

```
                <span class="tempRange">
                  <span class="minTemp" style="/* left:30% */">49˚</span>

                    <span class="bar" style="/* width: 100%; */margin-left: 0;"></span>

                      <span class="maxTemp" style="left:86%">72˚</span>
               </span>
```

here are the styles

```
.minTemp{
left: 0 !important;
}

.bar{
 width: 90% !important
}

.maxTemp{
 right: 0 !important
}
```

before
[image]

After pic
[image]

Now all the bars are the same size. Hope this helps!